# Integrability of piecewise functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f: [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and

$$x \mapsto \begin{cases} 
      0, & -1\leq x< 0 \\
      1, & 0\leq x \leq 1 
   \end{cases}$$

How can I show that this piecewise function does not have an antiderivative using the definition and partitions or is there an alternative approach to show this?

Update:

Here's my professor's approach for this and I find this slightly complicated, hence I'm looking for an alternative approach.

> Assume that, the function $f$ had an antiderivative $F : [−1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$.
>   Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus for every $x < 0$ holds:
>
> $$F(0) - F(x) = \int_x^0f(t)dt$$
>
> Now using the definition of an integral we can show that $\int_x^0f(t)dt = 0$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and $P:x, -\epsilon, 0$ be the partition for $[x, 0]$. Then
>
> $$S_p(f) = 0 \cdot (-\epsilon-x)+1\cdot \epsilon = \epsilon$$
>   and 
>   $$s_p(f) = 0 \cdot (-\epsilon-x)+0\cdot \epsilon = 0$$
>
> therefore $$\int_x^0f(t)dt = U(f) \leq \epsilon$$
>
> and $$\int_x^0f(t)dt = L(f) \ge 0$$
>
> so $$0 \leq \int_x^0f(t)dt \leq \epsilon$$
>
> Now we can see that $F(0) - F(x) = 0$ and from here
>
> $$\lim_{x\to0^-} \frac{F(x) - F(0)}{x-0} = 0 \neq 1 = f(x)$$
>
> which is a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't have an integral function? It is certainly integrable. Or perhaps you mean an antiderivative? What about $$x\mapsto \begin{cases} 0 & -1 \leqslant x \leqslant 0\\ x &\phantom -0\leqslant x \leqslant 1?\end{cases}$$

Comment: Updated the question. Antiderivative is translated to "integral function" in my native language. Apologies.

Comment: No worries. It does have an antiderivative, but it's piecewise differentiable on $[-1,1]$, not differentiable, so the FTC doesn't apply.

Comment: Edited the question once more.

Comment: What do you mean by "using the definition of partitions" ?

Comment: @Daniel It seems that your professor wants to show the value of the integral from $x<0$ to $0$ is $0$ using Darboux sums. Then it follows that $F(x)-F(0)=0$ for $x<0$ but $F'(0)=f(0)=1$ by hypothesis, and we get a contradiction. The alternative approach is [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) which immediately tells us $f$ can't be a derivative of a function.

Answer (score 2):

By Darboux's theorem, if $g$ is differentiable, then $g'$ has the intermediate value property. But that's not the case in the case of your function $f$. So, $f$ has no antiderivative.

Answer (score 0):

That function is integrable, and $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx=1$. Try thinking about the partition $-1<0<1$

Comment: Updated the question.